# Using await on Bluebird's promise is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await, bluebird

I am new to both `Promise` and `async/await`. I have the following piece of code that forms a mongoose query :

```
// Bluebird's promise

    const Prom = require('bluebird');

    let formSampleQuery = (customerQuery) => {
     return Prom.try(() => {
      customerQuery.where("age").lt("30");
      console.log("Formed Customer Query Object:\n", customerQuery);
      return Prom.resolve(customerQuery);
     })
    }
```

Then I have the following method that calls this method using `async/await` :

```
let Customer = require('./src/models/customer.model');

exports.executeQuery = () => {
 return Prom.try(async () => {
  let customerQuery = Customer.find().lean();
  customerQuery = await formSampleQuery(customerQuery);
  console.log('Customer Query at Execute Query:\n', customerQuery) // Output coming undefined at this point
  customerQuery.exec().then(res => {console.log(res)}); // At this point I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined"
 });
}
```

I get the complete `customerQuery` object at `formSampleQuery` method, but when the same thing is returned to `executeQuery` method, it becomes undefined and I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

The shortened output of the query object at `formCustomerQuery` is following..

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: { lean: true },
  _transforms: [],
  mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection {
     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
     opts:
      { bufferCommands: true,
        capped: false,
        '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
     name: 'customers',
     collectionName: 'customers',
   .........................
..........................
........................

  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true }
```

I know that at this point the query object has the condition I have specified. It shows up in the log

Comment: Why are you using Bluebird at all? You shouldn't need `Bluebird.try` around an `async function`.

Comment: `customerQuery` is a thenable, it has a `then` method already and you don't need to call `exec`. Resolving a promise with the query object will run the query and fulfill the promise with the query result.

Comment: What output do you get from the `Formed Customer Query Object` line?

Comment: @Bergi It still doesn't explain why what is being returned from `formSampleQuery` is undefined

Comment: @Bergi Updated with shortened output